# Parallel programming -explanation

Tags: parallel-processing

First of all,sorry for my bad English.I am not sure is this appropriate place to ask my question ,but i will try.I am starting to learn parallel programming,and it may be a stupid question,but i want to know this:when you run the simple Hello World parallel program that prints the name of every process,how does it work,considering the name of every process is stored in a same variable,i mean,if its parallel,how are they all(processes)using the same variable?

This is the code :

```
import mpi.*;
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
MPI.Init(args);
int me = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
int size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Size();
System.out.println("Hi from <"+me+">");
MPI.Finalize();
}
}
```

Comment: In MPI, each process executes the code except if you do something to prevent it. Hence, each process store its own variable `me`, its value being set to the value returned by `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();`. This value depends on the rank of the process, which is likely defined as `MPI.Init(args);` is called. Same thing for `size` : each process has a variable named `size`. Indeed, if one of the process modifies the value of its version of `size`, the value of `size` for the other process is not modified. It's called "distributed memory", where other tools (ex: openmp) use "shared memory" as default

Comment: Thank you @francis